# Django Crispy Formsets Only Using Last iteration -- overriding last results?

Tags: django, formsets

```
class BusinessMemberInlineForm(ModelForm):
    helper = FormHelper()
    username = 'no user found yet'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BusinessMemberInlineForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if hasattr(self.instance, 'user'):
            self.username = self.instance.user.username

        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Div(
                Div(
                    Column(
                        HTML('<b>%s</b>' % self.username)
                    ),
                    Column(
                        'can_post'
                    ),
                    Column(
                        'is_admin'
                    ),
                    Column(
                        'DELETE'
                    ),

                    'id',
                    'businessprofile',

                    css_class="span12"
                ),
                css_class="row-fluid"
            ),
        )

    class Meta:
        model = BusinessMember
        fields = ['can_post', 'is_admin']
```

This outputs something like:

`no user found yet   [x] can post?    [x] is admin?    [ ] remove?`

`no user found yet   [ ] can post?    [ ] is admin?    [ ] remove?`

Instead of:

`Admin    [x] can post?    [x] is admin?    [ ] remove?`

`Test user    [ ] can post?    [ ] is admin?    [ ] remove?`

There's something I'm not understanding here. It appears that it only saves the last instance of the Cripsy layout that is created (an empty model) so it only prints 'no user found yet'.

I am totally confused, I added `print self.username` and the values are all set properly.

How am I supposed to go about adding dynamic labels to formsets?

Answer (score 0):

Ugh!

I ended up having to make a custom widget to display the names in each field appropriately, this was so much harder than it should have been!

from django import forms

my utils/widgets.py

```
class DisplayTextWidget(forms.Widget):
    display_value = ""

    def __init__(self, attrs=None, display_value="Nothing here!"):
        self.display_value = display_value

        super(DisplayTextWidget, self).__init__(attrs)

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        return self.display_value
```

And then in forms.py

```
self.fields['user'].widget = DisplayTextWidget(display_value=self.instance.user.username)
```